# better practice to keep array item's unique

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have a array-type for  field `activity`,

And I need to do `UNION` operation many times for the field `activity`.

How to keep the activity's items be unique each other without duplicated.

I prefer high performance operation, because I have to do the kind of job billion times.

Thanks

```
print User.activity #["basketball", "baseball"]

User.activity =  (User.activity UNION ["football"])

# "football" should be inserted into activity
print User.activity
=> ["basketball", "baseball", "football"]

User.activity =  (User.activity UNION ["baseball"])

# it should be the same 
print User.activity
=> ["basketball", "baseball", "football"]
```

Comment: isn't that what [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) is for?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Set data structure instead of Array. There you can not have 2 objects which are the same.

Comment: With billion elements set might be a bit slow.

Comment: @Riko With a billion elements this is quite expected with whatever technique you use. You may find a solution which very sightly faster, but it will probably be uglier. The reason Set data structures exist anyway is exactly for such cases, so you should use them. Performance and code quality are things that must be treated with equal priority.

Comment: @Riko what do you mean? there's no hashArray in Mongodb.
if you're using hashes in mongoid, you will persist something like { basketball: true } or {basketball:"basketball"}, which doesn't make sense when using indexes on activity.

Comment: @Riko Read very porly, delete comment.